# Failed to get sharedPreferences value

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I want to get a value from sharedPreferences. I put the sharedPreferences on Config.java

```
public static final String SHARED_PREF_NAME = "myauthapp";
public static final String EMAIL_SHARED_PREF = "email";
public static final String LOGGEDIN_SHARED_PREF = "loggedin";
public static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://192.168.1.6/db_android_native/register.php";
```

And I try to get the value of `REGISTER_URL` on Register.java with this

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String RREGISTER_URL = sharedPreferences.getString(Config.REGISTER_URL, "Not Available");
```

And it's always return `Not Available`

Why it's not give me the value of Register_URL on Config.java ?

Comment: How you are saving to SharedPreference?

Comment: that is because it is not getting saved. please post your full code so that we can help you out.

Comment: Because the preference with name "http://192.168..." not exists? Anyway why do you need SharedPreferences for that?

Comment: @ParkerHalo You mean [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getString%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)?

Comment: @DebosmitRay my bad... thought it was a user-implemented method

Comment: @FebiMathew I HardCoded It. See the Config.java that I include above

Comment: @nvi9 http://192.168.1.6/db_android_native/register.php is the value. I need to get that on Register.java

Comment: You need to save the data before trying yo get that value. You should call sharedPreferences.edit().putString("name", "value").apply();

Comment: @FebiMathew even after I hardcode it ?

because I have hardcode it like this

public static final String REGISTER_URL = "http://192.168.1.6/db_android_native/register.php";

Comment: But you are not saving this value to SharedPreference. You are just hard coding it in the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the link stored by `REGISTER_URL` in Config.java, you should just simply get it with

```
String url = Config.REGISTER_URL;
```

Your code

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Config.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String RREGISTER_URL = sharedPreferences.getString(Config.REGISTER_URL, "Not Available");
```

looks for a preference with name provided by `Config.REGISTER_URL`, but it is not a good idea storing preferences with such a long and complex name. The `getSring` method returns it's provided default value until you have not saved any preference with that name like this:

```
sharedPreferences.edit().putString(prefname, value).apply();
```

Comment: so, if i hardcode it, i just need to write String url = Config.REGISTER_URL; ?

Comment: Thank you. I don't know that's the problem

Comment: Exactly, until REGISTER_URL is public and static in Config.java you can access its value from other classes